# SQL Remove all rows from duplicate rows blocks keeping only one from each block

Tags: sql, join

I have a database table that's supposed to represent the changes in state of an item.

so the columns of this table are : id, state, updatedAt.

I want to do a SQL query to display the changes of states of an item, what I mean by this is when an item passes from one state to another. so a result of a query should look like this.

```
 | id | state | date    
 | 1  |  A    | d1    
 | 2  |  B    | d2    
 | 3  |  A    | d3    
 | 4  |  C    | d4
```

The problem is that the table actually has multiple state columns, so the columns may actually be something like : id, state1, state2, updatedAt.

```
| id | state 1| state 2| date    
 | 1  |  A   |  X  | d1    
 | 2  |  A   |  Y  | d2    
 | 3  |  B   |  Y  | d3    
 | 4  |  B   |  Z  | d4
```

Basically I want to query for the history of one specific state column, for example, the result of the query for state 1 columns on the last table should be :

```
 | id | state 1| date    
 | 1  |  A   |  X  | d1    
 | 3  |  B   |  Y  | d3
```

I hope I made my problem clear.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ please :) - question:If state 1 is set, what are the possible values of state 2? And how are items identified in your table?

Comment: You might want to think about unpivoting the data and typifying the different states into types. That way you can partition byID and StateType to look back for changes, otherwise you are going to have a mess if you your columns get wide.

Comment: @Pilan I'm not really sure I understand your first question, but state 1 and 2 are both just strings that are not related to each other in any way. For your second question, this table is supposed to save states of different items, so there is a item_id column, but this really isn't a part of this problem, the query that I'm going to use is going to start by filtering the rows with a specific item_id, so I left this part out of the question to make it clearer. thank you.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/56d55/1) to the problem in sqlfiddle.com with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data you can use lag() to compare the current state with the previous:

```
select t.id, t.state1, t.state2, t.date
from (
  select *, lag(state1) over (order by date) prevstate1
  from tablename
) t  
where t.state1 <> t.prevstate1 or t.prevstate1 is null
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/88ZcHYM6NKybescUC92pDb/2).
Results:

```
| id  | state1 | state2 | date |
| --- | ------ | ------ | ---- |
| 1   | A      | X      | d1   |
| 3   | B      | Y      | d3   |
```